# Is there any tool that can turn C# upper case type and property names into CamelCase>

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know it's a very long shot, but with a nice large dictionary, a tool could recognise separate words in an upper case word/phrase and change the phrase to CamelCase.

Has anyone ever tried this in Visual Studio, and is anything available for VS2012-3?